# Are "code review" style questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

The beta Code Review stack exchange is doing rather well, with a lot of visitors and questions. It's an in-demand service:

http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Are "code review" style questions allowed here?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I think they should be allowed if the code relies on some Arduino-specific stuff, such as function calls or something related to hardware behaviour etc. The reason is that those elements may not be familiar or useful to non-Arduino programmers, so the question/answers won't have much value on the generic code review site.

Comment: I agree. Code can utilise platform specific features, which is pretty much our scope, and may not be of interest to people outside of this domain.